# AJAX Upload file straight after downloading it (without storing)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm making a JavaScript script that is going to essentially save an old game development sandbox website before the owners scrap it (and lose all of the games). I've created a script that downloads each game via AJAX, and would like to somehow upload it straight away, also using AJAX. How do I upload the downloaded file (that's stored in responseText, presumably) to a PHP page on another domain (that has cross origin headers enabled)?

I assume there must be a way of uploading the data from the first AJAX request, without transferring the responseText to another AJAX request (used to upload the file)? I've tried transferring the data, but as expected, it causes huge lag (and can crash the browser), as the files can be quite large.

Is there a way that an AJAX request can somehow upload individual packets as soon as they're recieved?

Thanks,

Dan.

Comment: Do it all server-side if possible. Perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php would help.

Comment: I can't as the site uses CAPTCHAs to verify manual interaction, before downloading the file. My script basically uses AJAX to capture the file that the CAPTCHA leads to.

Comment: using Blobs instead of text will help. a lot. `xhrDL.responseType="blob";` ... `xhrUL.send(xhrDL.response);` that keeps the blobs intact and avoids stringification/utf conversion overhead/ram usage.

Comment: it seems like it would be a lot easier/more reliable  to just download them all to the local machine and then FTP them to the php site all at once...

Answer (score 1):

You could use Firefox' `moz-chunked-text` and `moz-chunked-arraybuffer` response types. On the JavaScript side you can do something like this:

```js
function downloadUpload() {

  var downloadUrl = "server.com/largeFile.ext";
  var uploadUrl = "receiver.net/upload.php";
  var dataOffset = 0;

  xhrDownload = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhrDownload.open("GET", downloadUrl, true);
  xhrDownload.responseType = "moz-chunked-text"; // <- only works in Firefox
  xhrDownload.onprogress = uploadData;
  xhrDownload.send();

  function uploadData() {
    var data = {
      file: downloadUrl.substring(downloadUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
      offset: dataOffset,
      chunk: xhrDownload.responseText
    };
    xhrUpload = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrUpload.open("POST", uploadUrl, true);
    xhrUpload.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    xhrUpload.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    dataOffset += xhrDownload.responseText.length;
  };

}
```

On the PHP side you need something like this:

```php
$in = fopen("php://input", "r");
$postContent = stream_get_contents($in);
fclose($in); 

$o = json_decode($postContent);
file_put_contents($o->file . '-' . $o->offset . '.txt', $o->chunk);
```

These snippets will just give you the basic idea, you'll need to optimize the code yourself.